# Sql query for alter Table

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to alter a table and add a column at position which is after an existing column,
but I can't make it since getting the following

error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near 'AFTER'.

and the query I used is:

```
ALTER TABLE DealerGroup
ADD Status varchar(50)
AFTER Description;
```

Comment: You can't add a column to a specific position in a table.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft SQL Server does not support the `after` part, which I believe is specific to MySQL.

In any case the internal ordering of columns should not matter to you, unless you rely on getting an ordered result when doing `select *` which you shouldn't do anyway.

Comment: Is there any other solution to add a column in a specific position

Comment: @Meena Not without dropping and recreating the table I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a column to a specific position in a table. Actually the RDBMS (SQL Server in this case) doesn't care where a column resides in the order of a table.

When you add another column to a table, it always goes "last".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add the column after specified column because in database structure column order doesn't matter when you need to fetch the data, and also AFTER is not any keyword defined in it in case of alter table query.
OR if you still want to, then you have to drop the table and re-create it with required column ordering.